# Symfony date to string conversion

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig

Hey I am trying to make a href with current year and month, sent with get request to a controller function this way `<a href="{{ path('transactions', {'year' : date("Y"), 'month' : date("n")}) }}"></a>` and im getting "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given")."

I assume that I am getting an object instead of string but I have no clue how to overcome it and I didn't found any reasonable way to solve it.

Comment: I would use `$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` like `$date->format('y')` for the year and so on.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I'm not sure if I'm able to do this like that inside twig template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To default way to do it inside `twig` is using `NOW`, e.g.

```html
<a href="{{ path('transactions', {'year' : 'NOW'|date('Y'), 'month' : 'NOW'|date('m'), }) }}"></a>
```

[documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html#date)

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In a controler responsible for rendering this specific view i created 2 variables standing for current year and month and then i passed them to the view.

```
class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="main")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $current_year = date('Y');
        $current_month = date('n');
        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig', [
            'current_year' => $current_year,
            'current_month' => $current_month,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In a view i render a href with following:

```
<a href="{{ path('transactions', {'year' : current_year, 'month' : current_month}) }}"></a
```